# Running Analysis on Multiple geojson files

Tags: r, for-loop, gis, geojson, lapply

I have about 113 geojson files that I've previously mainly dealt with in QGIS. My goal now is to be able to simultaneously import all files into R and conduct analyses on the underlying attribute tables attached to each respective layer. I have already figured out the best way to import one file and conduct any needed analysis after converting into a data frame. The files that I have in the folder all look like this: 0cfb16c1-90c2-412d-bb60-2fec34c75e9a.geojson

The code I used for this step was:

```
library(rgdal)
map1 <- readOGR(dsn = "/Users/chris/Documents/GeorgetownMPPMSFS/McCourtMPP/BIGWork/BIGDataFiles/maps/sampled_maps/0cfb16c1-90c2-412d-bb60-2fec34c75e9a.geojson", layer = "0cfb16c1-90c2-412d-bb60-2fec34c75e9a")
summary(map1)
map1 <- as.data.frame(map1)
```

I want to run the same analysis I did on that map on all geojson files without having to do so one by one. The analysis I conducted related to electoral redistricting metrics and is included here:

```
cfbdata$reptotal <- (cfbdata$surveyed_republican_percentage/100)*cfbdata$surveyed_total
cfbdata$demtotal <- (cfbdata$surveyed_democrat_percentage/100)*cfbdata$surveyed_total
cfbdata$NAME <- NULL
aggdata <-aggregate(cfbdata, by=list(cfbdata$cluster), 
                    FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
# Rep district victory is 1 and Dem district victory is 0
aggdata$result <- ifelse(aggdata$reptotal > aggdata$demtotal,1, ifelse(aggdata$demtotal > aggdata$reptotal,0, NA))

EffGapCalc <- subset(aggdata, select=c("cluster","reptotal","demtotal","surveyed_total", "result"))

# Step 1: Calculate Dem Wasted, Rep Wasted, and Net Wasted

EffGapCalc$repwasted <- ifelse(EffGapCalc$result == 1, EffGapCalc$reptotal - (.51*EffGapCalc$surveyed_total), ifelse(EffGapCalc$result == 0, EffGapCalc$reptotal, NA))

EffGapCalc$demwasted <- ifelse(EffGapCalc$result == 0, EffGapCalc$demtotal - (.51 * EffGapCalc$surveyed_total), ifelse(EffGapCalc$result == 1, EffGapCalc$demtotal, NA))

EffGapCalc$netwasted <- abs(EffGapCalc$repwasted - EffGapCalc$demwasted)

# Step 2: Sum Total Wasted Rep and Dem Votes
totrepwasted <- sum(EffGapCalc$repwasted)
totdemwasted <- sum(EffGapCalc$demwasted)
netwaste <- ifelse(totrepwasted>totdemwasted, totrepwasted-totdemwasted, ifelse(totrepwasted<totdemwasted, totdemwasted-totrepwasted))
netwaste
# Democrats had a net waste (more wasted votes) of 74289.6

# Step 3: Divide Net Wasted by Total Number of Votes Case
sum(EffGapCalc$surveyed_total)
totalsurvtot <- sum(EffGapCalc$surveyed_total)
netwaste/totalsurvtot
# Efficiency Gap = .0359 [3.60%]
```

The goal is to run that same analysis for all 113 GEOJSON files and get a list of 113 "Efficiency Gap" numbers like the .0359 above.

I've searched through a number of questions on stackoverflow and elsewhere but have not found a suitable solution. While I initially thought a for loop would be best for this, based on what I've read elsewhere, it appears that `lapply()` actually might be the better route to go. The challenge I am having is ensuring the right import as part of 'lapply()'

The code I tried using that failed was:

```
library(rgdal)
fileNames <- list.files(path = "/Users/chris/Documents/GeorgetownMPPMSFS/McCourtMPP/BIGWork/BIGDataFiles/maps/sampled_maps", pattern="*.geojson", full.names = TRUE)

lapply(fileNames, function(x) {
  map1 <- readOGR(dsn = x, layer = x)
  map1 <- as.data.frame(map1)
  out <- map1$reptotal <- (map1$surveyed_republican_percentage/100)*map1$surveyed_total;
  map1$demtotal <- (map1$surveyed_democrat_percentage/100)*map1$surveyed_total;
  map1$NAME <- NULL;
  aggdata <-aggregate(map1, by=list(map1$cluster), 
                      FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE);
  aggdata$result <- ifelse(aggdata$reptotal > aggdata$demtotal,1, ifelse(aggdata$demtotal > aggdata$reptotal,0, NA));

  EffGapCalc <- subset(aggdata, select=c("cluster","reptotal","demtotal","surveyed_total", "result"));
  # Step 1: Calculate Dem Wasted, Rep Wasted, and Net Wasted
  EffGapCalc$repwasted <- ifelse(EffGapCalc$result == 1, EffGapCalc$reptotal - (.51*EffGapCalc$surveyed_total), ifelse(EffGapCalc$result == 0, EffGapCalc$reptotal, NA));

  EffGapCalc$demwasted <- ifelse(EffGapCalc$result == 0, EffGapCalc$demtotal - (.51 * EffGapCalc$surveyed_total), ifelse(EffGapCalc$result == 1, EffGapCalc$demtotal, NA));

  EffGapCalc$netwasted <- abs(EffGapCalc$repwasted - EffGapCalc$demwasted);

  # Step 2: Sum Total Wasted Rep and Dem Votes
  totrepwasted <- sum(EffGapCalc$repwasted);
  totdemwasted <- sum(EffGapCalc$demwasted);
  netwaste <- ifelse(totrepwasted>totdemwasted, totrepwasted-totdemwasted, ifelse(totrepwasted<totdemwasted, totdemwasted-totrepwasted));
  netwaste

  # Step 3: Divide Net Wasted by Total Number of Votes Case
  totalsurvtot <- sum(EffGapCalc$surveyed_total);
  netwaste/totalsurvtot;

  write.table(out, "/Users/chris/Documents/GeorgetownMPPMSFS/McCourtMPP/BIGWork/BIGDataFiles", sep="\t", quote=F, row.names=F, col.names=T)
})
```

I've been trying to figure this out for two days at this point and am only getting more confused. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: How did your last bit of code "fail"?

Comment: Sorry. I should've clarified that. The error message read: 

Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open layer
Called from: ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv, 
    swapAxisOrder = swapAxisOrder, require_geomType = require_geomType)

Comment: Simplify. Cut out everything from the function in your `lapply` and build it up again. Is it the first line, the `readOGR`, that's causing that? The more extraneous code you can get rid of the better. And you should test things as you write them, not write 30 lines of code and then hit a wall because the first one has a problem.

Comment: I suspect its because you are passing the *full* filename to `readOGR` both as the dsn and the layer arguments, and the layer should just be the layer name. If you can't easily get the layer name, use `ogrListLayers` on the DSN to get it.

Comment: Yes, I ran it without the other code in there and it was indeed the first part of the code with readOGR that was causing the problem.

Comment: I suspect you are correct in saying it's the full filename layer issue. I can use ogrListLayers to get the layer name for one DSN, but how would I add it in as part of lapply to get it for all files? Passing it through as the layer name in quotations obviously won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple test code:

```
lapply(fileNames, function(x) {
  map1 <- readOGR(dsn = x, layer = x)
}
```

Assuming that fails for your case, we know the problem is in that one line. That makes it easier for someone here to see its a simpler problem. Please always try and minimise your problems, it will help us help you and in many cases it lets you solve it yourself. Proceeding...

`readOGR` for a geoJSON needs a file path and a layer name, and that code is going to feed the file path as the layer name, like this, using a test file from the `geojson` package::

```
> testfile <- list.files(path = path, pattern="*.geojson", full.names = TRUE)[5]
```

quick check we've got it:

```
> file.exists(testfile)
[1] TRUE
```

Then try and read:

```
> d = readOGR(dsn=testfile, layer=testfile)
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open layer
```

So how do we get the layer name from the file path? We have `ogrListLayers` for that:

```
> ogrListLayers(testfile)
[1] "OGRGeoJSON"
attr(,"driver")
[1] "GeoJSON"
attr(,"nlayers")
[1] 1
```

Now that looks pretty weird but its a vector of layer names and some extra attributes that you can ignore for this purpose. The layer name of this test layer is "OGRGeoJSON". Assuming your geoJSONs are known to only be one layer you can do:

```
> d = readOGR(dsn=testfile, layer=ogrListLayers(testfile))
OGR data source with driver: GeoJSON 
Source: "/home/rowlings/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/geojson/examples/linestring_one.geojson", layer: "OGRGeoJSON"
with 1 features
It has 2 fields
Warning message:
In readOGR(dsn = testfile, layer = ogrListLayers(testfile)) :
  Z-dimension discarded
```

Now I think that either geoJSONs can only have one layer, or that `readOGR` defaults to the first layer, so if you know there's only one layer in your geoJSONs you can *leave out* the `layer=` argument and get an identical object returned:

```
> d2 = readOGR(dsn=testfile)
OGR data source with driver: GeoJSON 
Source: "/home/rowlings/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/geojson/examples/linestring_one.geojson", layer: "OGRGeoJSON"
with 1 features
It has 2 fields
Warning message:
In readOGR(dsn = testfile) : Z-dimension discarded
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response. It looks like I'm still caught at the layer part. While the file.exists(testfile) function returns true, the ogrListLayers(testfile) comes back with an error that says Error: length(dsn) == 1 is not TRUE. The full code here is: 

`testfile <- list.files(path = "/Users/chris/Documents/GeorgetownMPPMSFS/McCourtMPP/BIGWork/BIGDataFiles/maps/sampled_maps", pattern="*.geojson", full.names = TRUE)
file.exists(testfile)
ogrListLayers(testfile)`

Comment: What you've typed there passes the *vector* of *all* the geoJSON files that match that pattern. In my code `testfile` is a *single* geoJSON file. If you look you can see its the 5th (`[5]`) element of the files found in that package.

Comment: Right. Yes, I get how to do this with a single geoJSON file. The challenge I'm running into is doing it with multiple. I manged to get the lapply to go through all 113 of my geojson files using the code below, but ended up just overwriting the object 113 times instead of giving myself the ability to conduct the same analysis on each one. The code was:

`lapply(testfile, function(x) {
  map1 <- readOGR(dsn = x, layer = ogrListLayers(x))
})`

Comment: Now add the code that works with `map1` into the function in your lapply, like you have in your question, and writes a table at the end. We've fixed one bug...

Comment: At least I don't have to pass a separate `as.data.frame` function at least. But I still can't run operations in the lapply even with the overwriting. Including the next part of my code, what I most recently tried was: 

`lapply(testfile, function(x) {
  map1 <- readOGR(dsn = x, layer = ogrListLayers(x))
  out <- map1$reptotal <- (map1$surveyed_republican_percentage/100)*map1$surveyed_total;
  map1$demtotal <- (map1$surveyed_democrat_percentage/100)*map1$surveyed_total;
})`

Comment: What you return from your function inside `lapply` forms the elements of a list that is returned from `lapply`: Try: `Z = lapply(1:10, function(x){return(c(x,x*2))})` then look at `Z`. Sorry, this is getting into basic R programming now, and not really on-topic here.

Comment: OK. I think I figured it out. Instead of putting everything into the `lapply()` function, I created the function first and then passed it through `lapply` with the list of files. This gave me a list of 113 efficiency gaps, one for each file.

Comment: The final code looked like this (abridged to fit): 

`testfile <- list.files(path = "/Users/chris/Documents/GeorgetownMPPMSFS/McCourtMPP/BIGWork/BIGDataFiles/maps/sampled_maps", pattern="*.geojson", full.names = TRUE)

effgap <- function(filename) {
  map1 <- readOGR(dsn = filename, layer = ogrListLayers(filename))
  map1$reptotal <- (map1$surveyed_republican_percentage/100)*map1$surveyed_total;
  map1$demtotal <- (map1$surveyed_democrat_percentage/100)*map1$surveyed_total;
  map1$NAME <- NULL...
}

data <- lapply(testfile, effgap)
summary(data)`

Comment: So my data object essentially does what your Z object above did. Thanks!